# Java runtime error "NoClassDefFoundError" when referencing external project in Eclipse Android Project

Tags: java, android, jar

I am struggling with this issue for some time now and I think it is time that I appeal to the SO community.

When creating a new Android Project in Eclipse I am trying to reference an external project [for the time being, it is a simple class with a function that returns a string]. I have tried adding a reference to the project itself, I have tried exporting a .JAR file [adding it to the libs folder] but none of these solutions work, though at compile time the classes are seen, at run time I get the dreaded NoClassDefFoundError.

Because the JAR file is present both in the filesystem and the .classpath file, I believe there might be an issue with the way I exported the JAR.

I am not sure why it doesn't work or what the proper workflow is for adding such [non-Android] modules to a project. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*I have come across this issue in a lot of SO questions but I could not find any solutions that would work*

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had the same problem before. There are a couple things you can try.

Make sure that in the project properties for your external project that you have the the "Is Library" checked in the Android tab.

Then export the project as a jar file. (make sure you don't include and files other than the actual java class files. No AndroidManifest.xml etc...)

Include the jar file into your other project in the "libs" folder like you were doing before.

and you should be able to reference the class from the jar now.

If that still doesn't work, you might have an ordering issue, so right click the jar file, and select "Build Path" -> "add to build path", then go to the project properties of your non-library project and select Java Build Path -> Order and Export and move the jar file to the top of the list.

Hopefully this helps!

Cheers

Comment: Where should I find the Android Tab? If it's in Project Properties I can't find it for the external project; might it be because the external project is not an Android one? Just a standard Java.

Comment: If the external project is not an Android project, you shouldn't need to worry about this step. I believe you should just be able to export the project as a jar file. Make sure that when making the jar file that you aren't including system files. Sometimes they can conflict with the system files in your main project and cause issues.